# Application crash, restoring state

Tags: android, database

I've got a parent Activity from  which all others are derived. In my first-screen  activity(android.intent.category.LAUNCHER) I call methods from parent Activity which populate ram-sqlite dictionaries and it's the only place where it happens.

I'd like to investigate the following scenario: application crashes, those in-memory dictionaries get erased. Is it possible that on the next launch user will be placed on some activity different from "main" ? In that case dictionaries will remain empty and I'll get another crash. Is it possible ? What should I do to prevent it - create Application derived class and if-check, populate dictionaries there ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can  you explain better?

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you are asking, if you are getting a crash please provide some code and a logcat so we can try and help you

Comment: lol, getting a particular crush isn't the case -  I'm not getting a crush - ok ? But I might and in that case my dictionaries data might  be lost. So I ask whether the possibility of a user relaunching previously crushed application and being redirected right away to previously crushed activity exists. This previously crushed activity  might not be the "main"(launcher) activity where my dictionaries are populated. So in this case if dictionaries are blank and activity needs some data from them - it might be troublesome. Is it more clear now ?

Comment: Please Try to explain you issue properly so that one can help you.

Answer (score 1):

If the application crashes you wont be starting the same (crashed) activity again. But if some data are very important for the state of your main activity at launch, then you should be sure to save them persistently as they change. So you shouldn't only save your state in your activities onStop() methode.